# Show that every open ball in $R^2$ contains a point $x = (x_1, x_2)$ both of whose coordinates are rational

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that  every open ball in $R^2$ contains a point $x = (x_1, x_2)$ both of whose coordinates are rational.

What I have so far:

Let $B(y,r)$ be an arbitrary open ball centered at $y$ with radius $r$. My intuition tells me to proceed by some how using the denseness of the rational numbers, but i'm having trouble getting started with this.

Comment: Suggestion: Work first with open rectangles, then show every disk contains some open rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right.  And here's how to go from intuition to formal.

Let $r > 0$.  Then there is rational $q$ so that $x_1 < q < x_1+r$. And a rational $p$ so that  $x_2 < p < x_2 + r$ and $d((x_1,x_2),(q,p)) = \sqrt{(q-x_1)^2 + (p-x_2)^2} < \sqrt{r^2 + r^2} = \sqrt{2}r$ and .... oh, buggernuts!...It's too big....

So.... make it smaller ...

Okay, that's just fine...  if $r > r/500million > 0$ then there is a rational $q$ so that $x_1 < q < x_1 + r/500million$ and.....  $d((x_1,x_2),(q,p)) = \sqrt{(q-x_1)^2 + (p-x_2)^2} $$< \sqrt{(r/500million)^2 + (r/500million)^2} $$= \sqrt{2r^2/500million^2} $$= r*\frac {\sqrt{2}}{500million} < r$.

Okay, that was overkill.  .... but why *NOT* do overkill?  As long as we can get it small enough, it doesn't matter if we go way overboard.

Anywhooo.... if $r > r/\sqrt{2} > 0$ is the better choice.  Then "Then there is rational $q$ so that $x_1 < q < x_1+r/\sqrt{2}$. And a rational $p$ so that  $x_2 < p < x_2 + r/\sqrt{2}$ and $d((x_1,x_2),(q,p)) = \sqrt{(q-x_1)^2 + (p-x_2)^2} < \sqrt{(r/\sqrt{2})^2 + (r/\sqrt{2})^2} = r$" works perfectly.

Really.... all this stuff about getting the numbers to add up just right is just ...distracting, when the important thing is the *analysis*.  If $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $R$ we can find rationals arbitrarily close and we extend that to $\mathbb Q^m$ and $\mathbb R^m$.  The worrying about the arithmetic of square roots is .... not the relevant issue.

Comment: We could avoid the square roots by getting arbitrarily close in each coordinate seperately, and using the triangle inequality. Really we've just shifted the square roots to the triangle inequality proof but that's usually a given.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this thread is several years old by now, this will most likely won't be of much use to you, but for those who are stuck:

It's indeed possible and the following is one way of proving it.

Let $d_E:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$ be the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|$, where $|\cdot|$ is the usual norm on $\mathbb{R}$.

The trick is to choose $p=(p_1,\dots,p_n)\in \mathbb{Q^n}$ such that the $|x_i-p_i|<r\,/\,n$ for every $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

If you're wondering where the inequality above comes from.

This follows from the fact that:

(1) The Euclidean and manhattan norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|\,\|_E$ and $\|\,\|_M$ respectively, are equivalent. Meaning that there exist positive real numbers $C,D$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ $C\|x\|_E\leq\|x\|_M\leq D\|x\|_E$.

(2) The Euclidean distance can be defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
d_E:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n  \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\,\,
(x,y)\mapsto \|x-y\|_E.
\end{equation}

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$. An open ball of $R^2$ $B(x,r)=\{(y_1,y_2):|y_1-x_1|^2+|y_2-x_2|^2<r^2\}$ contains $I_1\times I_2, I_i=(x_i-r/4,x_i-r/4), i=1,2$. Since the rational are dense in $R$, there exists $y_i\in I_i\cap Q, and (y_1,y_2)\in B(x,r)$.